# Как вывести дочерние записи?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть сайт на CMS Wordpress. Используя плагин Toolset Types, создал 2 типа записей, во втором типе указал первый как родительский. Как теперь вывести только дочерние записи первого типа? Все стандартные выводы выводят поле  [post_parent] => 0.

Пример кода:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
$args = array( 'post_parent' => 1161,'post_type=quiz');
$myposts = new WP_Query($args);
echo "<pre>";
foreach( $myposts as $post ) {
    print_r($post);
}
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код

Comment: require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
$args = array( 'post_parent' => 1161,'post_type=quiz');
$myposts =  new WP_Query($args);
echo "<pre>";
foreach( $myposts as $post )
 {

   print_r($post);
 }
echo "</pre>";

Comment: Второй элемент массива неправильный, но дело не в этом. Скорее всего, плагин устанавливает соотношения между типами записей, а не конкретными постами.

Comment: @kagg-design, а как вытянуть эту зависимость? ведь где то она прописана, так как в админ панели стоит привязка к определенному посту записи  http://prntscr.com/f63iy0

Comment: Я с этим плагином не работал. Зависимость прописана, скорее всего, в post meta. Можно в базе посмотреть через phpmyadmin

Comment: @kagg-design, да нашел зависимость, прописана как вы и сказали в post meta, спасибо за наводку)

Comment: Welcome )) ....